# Finding appropriate m,n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I came across the following question in a book(with no solutions) that I have been solving:-
 Prove that for any positive integers $x$ and $y$, $x\not =y$, one can find positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that the given condition holds:-$$\frac {x^4+y^4+m^4}{x^2+y^2+m^2}=m^2+n$$ I substituted $x+y=s$ and $xy=p$. Therefore $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=s^2-2p$ and $x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=(s^2-2p)^2-2p^2=s^4-4s^2p+2p^2$. Substituting these values in the original equation we get $$\frac {s^4-4s^2p+2p^2+m^4}{s^2-2p+m^2}=m^2+n\\=>s^4-4s^2p+2p^2=m^2s^2-2pm^2+ns^2-2np+nm^2$$ This gives $n=-p$ and $m=s$ as solutions but we have to find positive $m,n$ so what should I do?

Comment: A general approach in contest problems is to try out small values of variables to get an idea how the land lies. Testing with $x=y=1$ is how I found out that there is a problem. I don't have the time to do it now, but I would start checking out what happens with $(x,y)=(2,1), (2,2), (3,1)$ et cetera. Often enough that leads to "a lightbulb experience". With truly taxing contest questions that is not enough, and you need something extra. Leaving this as a general piece of advice rather than a hint to this question, for I haven't checked it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using $s=x-y$ then slightly extending your existing argument, you can show that when $0 \ne |y| \ne |x| \ne 0$ then $m = \max(|x|,|y|)-\min(|x|,|y|), n=|x||y|$ is a solution with $m >0, n > 0$.

Generally it seems when the condition above does not hold then there is no such solution, however there are some solutions.

For $(x,y)=(6k,6k)$ we have $(m,n) = (3k,24k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(15k,15k)$ we have $(m,n) = (6k,175k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(33k,33k)$ we have $(m,n) = (22k,495k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(57k,57k)$ we have $(m,n) = (19k,2736k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(10k,0)$ we have $(m,n) = (5k,60k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(15k,0)$ we have $(m,n) = (5k,180k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(20k,0)$ we have $(m,n) = (15k,112k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(35k,0)$ we have $(m,n) = (5k,1176k^2)$

for $(x,y)=(65k,0)$ we have $(m,n) = (13k,3900k^2)$

and presumably many more.